# hg forget recursive

Tags: mercurial

is there a quick way to do a recursive

```
hg forget
```

on a folder? I accidentally versioned things i don't want

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What about

```
hg forget directory/*
```

?

Comment: oh my god that works, and i didn't need the wildcard. didn't think it was doable since tortoisehg doesn't allow it on folders

Comment: @davidosomething: yeah, I also overcomplicate things often ;-)